# typescript eslint rules. no-unused-vars#options for functions that return void

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

Consider this interface:

```
/*eslint no-unused-vars: ["warn", { "args": "after-used" }]*/
interface Whatever {
    x: number,
    y: number,
    myFunc: (arg1: number, arg2: string[]) => void // warning here
}
```

I get warnings:

1.- 'arg1' is defined but never used.eslintno-unused-vars
2.- 'arg2' is defined but never used.eslintno-unused-vars

I want my linter to check for variable usage in TS, but of course if function returns `void`, the variable wont be used in the type.

I'm surprised that that specific case cannot be arranged in the [documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-vars#options). I mean the specific case of check the variable usage in the type, but not if the function returns `void`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General principle:

```
If some JS eslint rule conflicts with TS, disable JS rule
```

In many cases TS rule may conflict with JS rule with same name

https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unused-vars/

#### How to Use

```
// .eslintrc.cjs
module.exports = {
  "rules": {
    // Note: you must disable the base rule as it can report incorrect errors
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "warn"
  }
};
```